# How to convert code to generic method - Object.class

Tags: java, oop, generics

I want to convert my entities to data access objects and I don't want to create a method for every entity. How can I convert my code into a generic method with generic return `Entity` and param `ObjectDTO`?

```
private ConcreteEntity convertToEntity(ConcreteObjectDTO objectDTO) throws ParseException {
    ConcreteEntity entity = modelMapper.map(objectDTO, ConcreteEntity.class);
    return entity;
}
```

I wrote the following code, but I don't know how to handle `Entity.class`

```
private <Entity, ObjectDTO> Entity convertToEntity(ObjectDTO objectDTO) throws ParseException {
    Entity entity = modelMapper.map(objectDTO, Entity.class);
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method will need to take a `Class` instance as a parameter so it can forward the right class to `modelMapper.map()`. That means `Class<E>` where `E extends Entity`. Note that it's convention to give generic types single letter names.

Similarly, the `ObjectDTO` should also be genericized as `O extends ObjectDTO` or equivalent.

```
private <O extends ObjectDTO, E extends Entity> E convertToEntity(O objectDTO, Class<E> entityClass) throws ParseException {
    return modelMapper.map(objectDTO, entityClass);
}
```

You may be able to skip genericizing the DTO parameter. It's probably not necessary.

```
private <E extends Entity> E convertToEntity(ObjectDTO objectDTO, Class<E> entityClass) throws ParseException {
    return modelMapper.map(objectDTO, entityClass);
}
```